# RazorPages How to pass GET parameters to OnGet?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a RazorPages application and it's index page has a list of items. I want this page to show only 50 elements of list and decide what items to show using GET parameter, for example  if I pass `?page=2` to page it must display elements from 51 to 100

As I have found, I can handle this type of request in `OnGet` like that:

```
public void OnGet(int page)
```

But when I open page - the `page` parameter in `OnGet` is always 0 even if I pass '?page=2' or something like this

I tried also using string instead of int and always got "/Index"

What is the correct way to handle these parameters in OnGet?

Comment: What's your route pattern? (typically defined in `Configure` in `Startup.cs`)

Comment: I just checked Startup.cs and did not find anything related to route pattern. I'm new to RazorPages and may not know what is route pattern

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing).

Comment: I changed line with `@page` to `@page "{pageNumber:int?}"` and changed OnGet to `OnGet(int pageNumber)`. Now if I specify url `localhost/2` - pageNumber in OnGet is 2. That's not really what I needed but I will use this. I suppose that I almost solved my problem and I just need to change that string after `@page` somehow

Comment: Oh, I didn't see last comment, I'll check that page

Comment: You cannot use "page" as a parameter. I learned this the hard way. See @Serge answer for workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add in you page view

```
@page "{pageNum:int?}"
```

and model

```
public void OnGet(int? pageNum)
```

Comment: I wrote a comment under my post that I changed `@page` into `@page "{pageNumber:int?}"`. What is the difference between `{pageNum?:int}` and `{pageNum:int?}` ?

Comment: The only difference I found is that when I use `{pageNum?:int}` I get an error and when I use `{pageNum:int?}` - I don't get any errors...

Comment: @MikhailKriseev The difference is that pageNum? is optional, url will be valid without it  too, but if you use PageNum  you will have always supply  pageNum in your url. You can try PageNum?:int? too and pls let me know if it is working.

Comment: I used PageNumber, not PageNum, and with PageNumber?:int? it still says `The route parameter name 'pageNumber?' is invalid`

Comment: @MikhailKriseev Thanks for the feedback, it is really strange, never met something like this before. You are the first.

Comment: Here's the full error message: `The route parameter name 'pageNumber?' is invalid. Route parameter names must be non-empty and cannot contain these characters: '{', '}', '/'. The '?' character marks a parameter as optional, and can occur only at the end of the parameter. The '*' character marks a parameter as catch-all, and can occur only at the start of the parameter.` if it's needed

Comment: @MikhailKriseev Thank you, you are right , i found the documentation and fixed my answer. I haven' t used  razor pages for many many years  and can forget something.